# AJAX submit ignored if comments form is loaded with AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, javascript, comments

In D7, I have a custom module enabling AJAX form submission on comments forms.  That is working great.

I also have comments being loaded in the [commentsblock](http://drupal.org/project/commentsblock) module using [block_refresh](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) with the below snippet.  That works great to display comments and the form.  However, the AJAX form submission stops working.

I tried calling `$Drupal.attachBehaviors()` (seen below) and `$Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#comment-form'))` but it won't add AJAX handlers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.loadFirstSlideComments = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('#block-block-1 .content').once('load-first-slide-comments').load('/block_refresh/commentsblock/comment_form_block/node/2', 
            function() {
              Drupal.attachBehaviors();
            });
      }
    };
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not good idea to use id. IDs are changing via AJAX. Are you sure `#block-block-1` element exists after first AJAX request?

Comment: Good thought, it does exist.  Just double-checked to be sure.  That block is a parent container purely for this purpose.

Comment: AJAX debugging requires full information about what's happening. Are your form are reloading with AJAX `.load`? Try to debug `attachBehaviors` method.

Comment: I switched it over so comments show on the slideshow and have the AJAX submission processing done on them.  Then when I call `.load` (above in question) on that block it works.  So kinda fixed, but ultimately this should be do-able without that.  Recommendations on what/how to debug with `attachBehaviors`?